# Queries executed per oracle session

Tags: oracle

Is there anyway to check the query statistics (like executed , execution time ...) of queries executed per oracle session. ( for all active/inactive sessions)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to start is to have a look at the system view `V$SESSION`. If you can't see it, ask your DBA to get access to it.

Description is in the Oracle Reference at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/dynviews_3016.htm#i1414383